# Encrypted chat using any smartphone. Is it legal?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, legal, android

Here's my case. We have written app for Android smartphones which allows users to exchange secured cipher messages. For key-exchange we're using elliptic curve 112 bits, for messaging we're using DES 56 bits. We have chosen weak enough cryptography in order to satisfy all kind of limitations applied to cryptographic methods/algorithms and so on. Messages encrypted from sender to recipient (along whole channel).

Question: is it legal? Let's say for U.S. or EU countries? To my knowledge if algorithms confirms to Wassenaar Arrangement it's safe enough to use them.

Am I right? Or there're some "hidden string"?

Comment: Not a good idea to get legal advice from a bunch of guys on the internet. Consult a lawyer.

Comment: Sure I will do, but sometimes bunch of guys are also useful :)

Comment: First, as Terry said, you should consult a lawyer you trust for legal questions.  Second, why even bother encrypting if your crypto is weak?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: BTW: I've tried to consult with 2 or 3 lawyers but no of them was able to help me, since they even do not understand topic, saying "what a hell is 56 bits"?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about getting legal advice. Consult a lawyer instead.

Comment: As pointed out - this isn't a security question, so is off topic here.

Comment: Why even use encryption if you use that weak encryption? If you call that "secured" you're lying to your customers.

Comment: Just get the export permission and use proper crypto. Getting it isn't that hard nowadays.